# Update dummy variable based on three variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset PCD that containing papers, versions, release date and dummy variable for proofreading.

```
PCD <- read.table(text = "
Paper Version Week     Major_version Proofread
YYYYY 1.0     201405    1             1
YYYYY 1.1     201407    1             0
YYYYY 2.0     201436    2             0 
YYYYY 2.1     201439    2             1
YYYYY 2.2     201449    2             0 
ZZZZZ 3.4     201350    3             0
ZZZZZ 3.5     201510    3             0 
XXXXX 1.0     201723    1             0
XXXXX 1.1     201748    1             1
XXXXX 1.2     201750    1             1
XXXXX 2.0     201810    2             0
XXXXX 2.1     201815    2             0
XXXXX 2.2     201817    2             1 
XXXXX 2.3     201825    2             0
QQQQQ 2.0     201605    2             1
QQQQQ 3.0     201610    3             1
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If at some point a major version was proofread and received a minor update, I want to keep the dummy for the proofread version, until the major version of that paper changes to newer version. So the desired output would be this.

```
Paper Version Week     Major_version Proofread
YYYYY 1.0     201405    1             1
YYYYY 1.1     201407    1             1
YYYYY 2.0     201436    2             0 
YYYYY 2.1     201439    2             1
YYYYY 2.2     201449    2             1  
ZZZZZ 3.4     201350    3             0
ZZZZZ 3.5     201510    3             0 
XXXXX 1.0     201723    1             0
XXXXX 1.1     201748    1             1
XXXXX 1.2     201750    1             1
XXXXX 2.0     201810    2             0
XXXXX 2.1     201815    2             0
XXXXX 2.2     201817    2             1 
XXXXX 2.3     201825    2             1
QQQQQ 2.0     201605    2             1
QQQQQ 3.0     201610    3             1
```

I think that something like

```
PCD %>% group_by(Paper, Major_version)
```

would be a good starting point, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I don't understand what is a condition? Why is Proofread in second row 1 in second table?

Comment: @Mislav Because the previous version, before the minor update, was proofread. I want to assume that any version with a minor update after a proofread version is also proofread, because a minor update does not change that much to the document. This is done until a new major version of the document is released.

Comment: Than you need another column `minor update`?

Comment: @Mislav if that helps me to get the right dummy column, yes :)

Comment: Can you provide first table using dput command in R?

Comment: @Mislav read.table works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want to use the "dplyr" package, here is a code that does what you want:

```
PCD %>% 
  arrange(Paper, Version) %>%
  group_by(Paper, Major_version) %>% 
  mutate(Proofread = 1 * (cumsum(Proofread) >= 1 ))
```

The idea is to use cumsum() within each subgroup to check with a logical test whether there has been any proofreading so far. The rest is self-explanatory.

The second line is not mandatory if your data.frame is well ordered as in your example, but should save you some troubles down the line...